# Trying to understand the evaluation of parameters (if some arithmetic operations are involved) passed to a function

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I was trying to understand the `cdecl` calling convention and I stumbled on this weird behaviour.

As per `cdecl` standards, the calling function stores the parameters from Right to Left on to the stack and then calls the target function. So I assumed the parameters would be evaluated left to right since that would resemble a stack flow or it could still evaluate from right to left given the `cdecl` convention for storing the parameters.

But the output of the below program has baffled me. Below is a simple program I wrote to understand the evaluation of parameters.

```
void fun (int a, int b, int c) {    
    printf("a: %d, b: %d, c: %d\n", a, b, c);
}    

int main()    
{
    int i = 2; 
    fun(i, i++, i);
}
```

Expected Output: `a: 3, b: 2, c: 2 or a: 2, b: 2, c: 3`

Actual Output: `a: 3, b: 2, c: 3`

```
 gcc --version
 gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
 warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Can someone throw some light on this?

Comment: See the other question, it clearly explains why "stores the parameters from Right to Left" is completely unrelated to the order of evaluation.

Comment: This code causes undefined behaviour (due to mixing of `i` and `i++`) regardless of any order of evaluation or parameter storage issues, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common confusion: there are two unary operators that increment an a number: `var++` and `++var`. `var++` will add one to the variable *after* passing the value of the variable to the function, while `++var` will add one *before* the data is passed to the function.

Try changing the position of the `++` operator and see what happens.

Quick example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
     int i = 5;
     std::cout << i << std::endl; //Prints "5"
     std::cout << i++ << std::endl; //Also prints "5", but after i is 6
     std::cout << ++i << std:: endl; //Prints "7"
```

Comment: I changed it to fun (i, i, i++);  i got the following ouput.. a: 3, b: 3, c: 2. This make sense to me since I can conclude that the evaluation is happening Right to Left.. But in the Previous case.. Its ambiguous.

Comment: Not necessarily "after the line of code is over".  Simply "the value of the postincrement is the old value of the variable".

Comment: And now you're encouraging use of undefined behavior :(

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm trying to make the use of pre versus post unary increment clear to the asker. I'll erase my comment as that was unintended.

Comment: @BenVoigt regard "after the line is over" I should have been clear that that particular phrasing was an oversimplification for the sake of the asker. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: If i change it to fun(i,++i,i) i get the following output: a:3 b:3 c:3.. So does that mean if any parameter needs some evaluation will be evaluated and rest will be passed or rather will be pushed on to the stack ?

Comment: @VinKris: No, there is no such guarantee.  Read the answers to the question I closed yours as a duplicate of.

Comment: @VinKris You shouldn't rely on using `++` as a prefix when passing to a function. As @BenVoigt was reminding me, doing so is undefined behavior (so the compiler can choose how to handle that situation if at all).

Comment: BenVoigt, ahjohnston25 thanks for the quick answers..